# npm tests hangs indefinitely even once complete

Tags: npm, bitbucket-pipelines

Trying to run npm test script in my bitbucket pipelines build and all tests pass but then just hangs and doesn't move onto the next script.

So my test script is: `"test": "mocha src/**/*.spec.ts --require ts-node/register --reporter spec",`

which is getting called in my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file

```
- yarn install
- yarn run test
- yarn run prestart:prod
```

So yarn install runs, yarn test runs but then hangs and run prestart:prod never runs.

Any reason it would just hang? Do I need to set `--watch=false` or anything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Needed to add flag `--exit` to tell mocha to exit test state

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used yarn nor mocha, but I used pipelines with Karma and I had to set a flag to make it run once, instead of continuous. Hope this helps.